# Calculate the norm of a polynomial knowing inner product

Tags: normed-spaces, inner-products

The polynomial $p(x) = 3 - 2x$ is a polynomial in an inner product space with the inner product defined as

$$ \langle p, q \rangle = \int_0^1 p(x)q(x) \, dx$$

on the interval $[0, 1]$ in the vector space $\mathbb{P}^{2}$. The question is to find the norm of $p(x)$, which I know you calculate by doing

**$$ \|p(x)\| = \sqrt{\langle p, p \rangle} = \sqrt{\int_0^1 (4x^2-12x+9) dx}
$$**

I did the problem on my own, and I got the answer
 **$$\|p(x)\| = \sqrt{\frac{13}{3}}.$$**

Is this the correct answer? I feel like it would be, but I'm not exactly sure

Comment: This is correct

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Also, there is very little room for "feelings" here.

Comment: This is correct, but it is important to clarify your inner product definition in the case that your polynomial has complex values, in this case $$ \langle p, q \rangle = \int_0^1 \; p(x) \overline{q(x)} \, \mathrm{d}x, $$ where $\overline{q(x)}$ denotes the conjugate of $q(x)$. This is why $$\Vert p \Vert_2 = \sqrt{ \langle p, p \rangle } = \int_0^1 \; p(x) \overline{p(x)} \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_0^1 \; \left| p(x) \right|^2 \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your calculations are correct.

Comment: Great, thanks for clarifying for me.