# How to calculate Norm for a Polynomial in P(R) of (1+x)

Tags: matrix-norms

Editing my question to add more details.

I am doing a course for data science where the first module is Linear Algebra. In one of the chapter about Norm, they taught about vectors.

In practice quiz question is "Question 5
Find the norm of the following polynomial in P(R) of (1+x)."

For this i know that
∥1+x∥= ∫ (1+x)^2
​
but the answer is √7/3 which i am not able to understand how.

I found another question in this site at [LINK](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2168705/calculate-the-norm-of-a-polynomial-knowing-inner-product) but again there is no explanation for how he got the answer.

I am looking reference where i can read and study about norm for a polynomial so that I can calculate the norm for a polynomial P(R) of (1+x).

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)'s a quick guide.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: Finally, it is impossible to answer your question, because there exists more than one norm that can be defined on the space of polynomials. So unless you tell us how the norm is defined, it is impossible for us to help you.

Comment: does P(R) mean polynomial with real coefficients?

Comment: My question is something similar to below link. I want to understand how the user got the answer for this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2168705/calculate-the-norm-of-a-polynomial-knowing-inner-product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am able to figure out how to solve this. I have to apply the calculus which I was missing.

For my question ||1+x||=square root of ∫(1+x)^2 dx

1. I have to solve power of 2 which will give me x^2 +2x+1
2. Then I have to apply anti derivative on this which will give me (x^3/3)(x:1->0)+2(x^2/2)(x:1->0)+1
3. This will give me ((1^3/3)-0^3/3)+ 2((1^2/2)-0^2/2) +1)
4. Then i will have (1/3+ 2*1/2 +1)
5. This will result in 1/3 + 1 + 1
6. 1/3 +2
7. (1+6)/3
8. 7/3
9. Last we need to take the square root of 7/3 to reach the ans

I am sorry as i am new to this site and was not able to explain the answer in more paper symbols. If some can help me and explain the ans in paper symbols, that will be great.

Comment: You can find a MathJax primer [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

If the inner product $\langle .,.  \rangle$ is defined as exactly as in the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2168705/calculate-the-norm-of-a-polynomial-knowing-inner-product), you mentioned in your comment, then:

$$
\|1+x\|  = \sqrt{\int_0^1 (1+x)^2 dx}
$$
Convince yourself that
$$
\int_0^1 (1+x)^2 dx=\frac{7}{3}.
$$
Then insert this result in above to get:
$$
\|1+x\|= \sqrt{\frac{7}{3}}
$$
Maybe this is what you wanted? If not, please let me know, then I can delete this answer.

Comment: How do you got 7/3? I need to understand how to calculate this to get 7/3